# Best way of parsing date and time in golang

Tags: performance, parsing, date, time, go

I have a lot of datetime values incoming as string into my golang program.
The format is fixed in number of digit:

```
2006/01/02 15:04:05
```

I started to parse these dates with the [time.Parse](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) function

```
const dtFormat = "2006/01/02 15:04:05"

func ParseDate1(strdate string) (time.Time, error) {
    return time.Parse(dtFormat, strdate)
}
```

but I had some performances issue with my program. Thus I tried to tune it by writting my own parsing function, taking into account that my format is kind of fixed:

```
func ParseDate2(strdate string) (time.Time, error) {
    year, _ := strconv.Atoi(strdate[:4])
    month, _ := strconv.Atoi(strdate[5:7])
    day, _ := strconv.Atoi(strdate[8:10])
    hour, _ := strconv.Atoi(strdate[11:13])
    minute, _ := strconv.Atoi(strdate[14:16])
    second, _ := strconv.Atoi(strdate[17:19])

    return time.Date(year, time.Month(month), day, hour, minute, second, 0, time.UTC), nil
}
```

finally I did a benchmark on top of these 2 functions and got the following result:

```
 BenchmarkParseDate1      5000000               343 ns/op
 BenchmarkParseDate2     10000000               248 ns/op
```

This is a performance improvement by 27%.
Is there a better way in terms of performances that could improve such datetime parsing ?

Comment: How many dates need to be parsed?

Comment: I am receiving live logs through zmq push/pull. It is a continuous stream. I bulk log lines to limit the number of transactions. The main program logs at 5000 TPS at peak time. Under normal conditions it is 500 TPS.

Comment: Can you just store the dates as a string, and convert them to actual dates later, if you ever need to read the data?  If this is a live update to a dashboard of some sort, do you really need to update the dashboard 5000 times per second?

Comment: I want to produce live graph with Max,Min,Average. Also I plan do some more maths if possible. Thus I would like to avoid any drop of data if possible.
But I understand your point, I need to check if dropping part of the metrics would impact my figures in case of big number of inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would expect to make your entire program much faster. For example, `ParseDate3`,

```
func ParseDate3(date []byte) (time.Time, error) {
    year := (((int(date[0])-'0')*10+int(date[1])-'0')*10+int(date[2])-'0')*10 + int(date[3]) - '0'
    month := time.Month((int(date[5])-'0')*10 + int(date[6]) - '0')
    day := (int(date[8])-'0')*10 + int(date[9]) - '0'
    hour := (int(date[11])-'0')*10 + int(date[12]) - '0'
    minute := (int(date[14])-'0')*10 + int(date[15]) - '0'
    second := (int(date[17])-'0')*10 + int(date[18]) - '0'
    return time.Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, 0, time.UTC), nil
}
```

Benchmarks:

```
$ go test -bench=.
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
BenchmarkParseDate1  5000000           308 ns/op
BenchmarkParseDate2 10000000           225 ns/op
BenchmarkParseDate3 30000000            44.9 ns/op
ok      so/test 5.741s
$ go test -bench=.
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
BenchmarkParseDate1  5000000           308 ns/op
BenchmarkParseDate2 10000000           226 ns/op
BenchmarkParseDate3 30000000            45.4 ns/op
ok      so/test 5.757s
$ go test -bench=.
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
BenchmarkParseDate1  5000000           312 ns/op
BenchmarkParseDate2 10000000           225 ns/op
BenchmarkParseDate3 30000000            45.0 ns/op
ok      so/test 5.761s
$
```

Reference:

[Profiling Go Programs](http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs)

---

If you insist on using `date string`, use `ParseDate4`,

```
func ParseDate4(date string) (time.Time, error) {
    year := (((int(date[0])-'0')*10+int(date[1])-'0')*10+int(date[2])-'0')*10 + int(date[3]) - '0'
    month := time.Month((int(date[5])-'0')*10 + int(date[6]) - '0')
    day := (int(date[8])-'0')*10 + int(date[9]) - '0'
    hour := (int(date[11])-'0')*10 + int(date[12]) - '0'
    minute := (int(date[14])-'0')*10 + int(date[15]) - '0'
    second := (int(date[17])-'0')*10 + int(date[18]) - '0'
    return time.Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, 0, time.UTC), nil
}
```

Comment: Damn, I started working on this out of curiosity, but I got nowhere near 45ns/op. Learnt not to think too complex I guess :) Thanks!

Comment: I don't getthe same values in my benchmark:

BenchmarkParseData1      5000000               331 ns/op

BenchmarkParseData2     10000000               256 ns/op

BenchmarkParseData3     20000000               143 ns/op


Still it gives better results. Thanks

Comment: @dbenque: That's because you are using `string` instead of `[]byte` so there is a conversion cost. Use `ParseDate4` for `date string`. See my revised answer. What are your results now?

Comment: BenchmarkParseData1      5000000               328 ns/op
BenchmarkParseData2     10000000               242 ns/op
BenchmarkParseData3     20000000               135 ns/op
BenchmarkParseData4     50000000                52.3 ns/op    .... Thanks again.

Comment: First character in the above formula should be multiplied by 100, not 10 (`int(date[0])-'0')*100`). @dbenque I also encourage you to make sure the input is validated before applying this into production (it will cost you some nanoseconds though;-))

Comment: @tomasz: That's not the proper fix. I've made the proper fix.

Comment: @peterSO: it wasn't me who fixed your code, just pointed out the issue. thanks for sorting out.

Answer (score 7):

From what you have already showed, using `strconv.Atoi` directly improved your performance. You can push it further and roll your own `atoi` for your particular use case.

You expect each item to be a positive base-10 number. You also know it can't overflow, because max length of string representation passed is 4. The only error possible is then a non-digit character in the string. Knowing this, we can simply do the following:

```
var atoiError = errors.New("invalid number")
func atoi(s string) (x int, err error) {
    i := 0
    for ; i < len(s); i++ {
        c := s[i]
        if c < '0' || c > '9' {
            err = atoiError
            return
        }
        x = x*10 + int(c) - '0'
    }
    return
}
```

Wrapping this into `ParseDate3`, I have the following result:

```
BenchmarkParseDate1  5000000           355 ns/op
BenchmarkParseDate2 10000000           278 ns/op
BenchmarkParseDate3 20000000            88 ns/op
```

You could make it faster by not returning an error in `atoi`, but I encourage you to test the input anyway (unless it's validated somewhere else in your code).

**Alternative atoi approach after seeing the inlined solution:**

Pushing this even further, you could take advantage of the fact that all but one of passed strings are 2-digit long (year is 4-digit, but it's multiply of two). Creating atoi taking 2-digit string would eliminate the `for` loop. Example:

```
// Converts string of 2 characters into a positive integer, returns -1 on error
func atoi2(s string) int {
    x := uint(s[0]) - uint('0')
    y := uint(s[1]) - uint('0')
    if x > 9 || y > 9 {
        return -1 // error
    }
    return int(x*10 + y)
}
```

Converting year into the number would need 2-step approach then:

```
year := atoi2(strdate[0:2])*100 + atoi2(strdate[2:4])
```

This gives additional improvement:

```
BenchmarkParseDate4 50000000            61 ns/op
```

Note that inlined version proposed by @peterSO is only slightly faster (54 ns/op in my case), but the solution above gives you possibility of error checking, while the inlined version would blindly take all the characters converting them into dates.

Comment: Just how critical the extra nanoseconds are depends on use case, but I prefer this solution for being clear and simple to read, as well as fast.